# Form and user validation in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I started to work with django, and it is great framework. However, my project is made of free and premium version. How to check does user have any special permissions in forms and give him some extra options in form if has, if not to show normal.

I hope you understand question.

Comment: well, how is your user model? how do you difference between a premium and normal user?

Comment: I have a table 'userprofiles' where is stored field 'account_type' with value 1 or 2 (free, premium)

Comment: how is your form and views??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your views, but i think you can do something like that:

```
# in forms.py

class NormalUserForm(forms.Form):
   # Your normal account form here
   name = forms.CharField()


class PremiumUserForm(NormalUserForm):
    # inherit from NormalUserForm, and add fields
    premium_field = forms.TextField()

# in views.py

def is_premium(user):
    # Find a better way
    return user.userprofile.account_type == 2


class SomtFormView(FormView):
    template = 'sometemplate.html'

    def get_form_class(self):
        if is_premium(self.request.user)
            return PremiumUserForm
        return NormalUserForm
```